# Using png files as emojis in android keyboad

Tags: android, keyboard, png, emoji

I want to build a keyboard for android which will have .png images as emojis. So far i have tried HTML ImageGetter, SpannableString. I have also tried to make a custom font but that also did not work. I am using Input connection service.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand you well. but this open source project [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) may help you. That's a textView which can show emoji.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Emojicon adds the emojis only to its textview. I want the emojis to be added to the default messaging of android...